# Prevent ibid tracking in natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to prevent `natbib` from replacing a list of author names by a long dash, which is the default behavior for citations with the same authors. Why? Because I'm using `\bibentry` to place full citations in a CV and actually want the full citation.

I'm using packages `bibentry`, `natbib` and the `amnatnat.bst` style.

First post, sorry for the lack of fancy formatting, links, etc...

UPDATE: Can I modify the following function in amnatnat.bst to prevent the substitution?

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
         { "---{}---{}---" }
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot be done with `amnatnat.bst`. When you run `bibtex` `amnatnat.bst` replaces the author lists with `---{}---{}---` if the authors list in the entry `bibtex` is currently processing in the same as the previous one, and the information about the authors (full) names is lost. Thus the only alternative I see is to change the `\bibliographystyle`.

If you want to keep the dash for repeated authors in the bibliography and using the full citation in the text, a possible solution is to use `biblatex` and to use the `\fullcite{<key>}` command instead of `\bibentry{<key>`.

**EDIT**

The simplest way to modify the function in `amnatnat.bst` is to replace definition of the `FUNCTION {name.or.dash}` with

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ skip$ }
```

This would produce a "standard" entry wihtout the dash for repeated names (both in the bibliography and in `\bibentry`.

If one wants to have both the full references with `\bibentry{<key>}` and the dash in the bibliography the function can be modified as follows:

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
         { "\andash{" oldname * "}" * }
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

and then using the following code in the LaTeX source

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\andash}[1]{#1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand{\andash}[1]{---{}---{}---}}
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand\andash[1]{#1}}
```

The following is an MWE illustrating the usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{first,
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "First Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2012
}
@Article{second,
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "Second Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
@Article{third,
  author = "More, First",
  title = "Third Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\andash}[1]{#1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand{\andash}[1]{---{}---{}---}}
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand\andash[1]{#1}}

\begin{document}
Testing normal citations
\cite{first} 
\cite{second}
\cite{third}

\bibliographystyle{amnatnat}
\nobibliography{\jobname}

Testing \verb|\bibentry|

\bibentry{first}

\bibentry{second}


\bibliography{\jobname}

\section*{More Testing}
Testing \verb|\bibentry| again after the bibliography

\bibentry{second}

\bibentry{first}

\end{document}
```

PS Comment one of the `\bibliography`, `\nobibliography` before running `bibtex`.

Comment: Thanks! What about modifying amnatnat.bst then? See update to my question.

Comment: Substituting the definition of name.or.dash as in your first suggestion generates errors when I run bibtex (`You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry <key>
while executing---line 1658 of file amnatnat.bst
Name 1 in "<author-list>" has a comma at the end for entry C<key>
while executing---line 1658 of file amnatnat.bst`). But the second suggestion works.