# \bibentry producing dashes for authors with custom bst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, best-practices, bibentry

I made a custom .bst file using `makebst` and chose the option for producing a long dash for repeated author names in the bibliography (option `nmdash,nmd-3`).  (I'm using bibtex with natbib and author-year citations.) This works as intended in the bibliography (produced with `\bibliography{}`). However, I need to include certain entries at various points in the text, and then primarily in isolation. When I use `\bibentry{key}` for a reference that appears in the bibliography with the authors replaced by a long dash, the long dash is used here too. When the reference is printed by itself like that, the dash is meaningless. Is this avoidable with my current setup or will I have to switch to biblatex or something else?

I'm not sure how to create an MWE for this without attaching the bst file (which I'd be happy to do if it'd be helpful, of course) --- sorry.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71227/5872

Comment: @henrique Thanks, I was not able to find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to recreate the bst file you created with makebst. The
file above is only a stripped version (I removed everything commented
with `latexpand`) of the `dbj` file created running `tex makebst.tex`
with all the default options except for the `ay` (for author-year),
`nmdash` and `nmd-3`:

```
%% Stripped version of driver file produced from merlin.mbs
\input docstrip
\preamble
----------------------------------------
***  ***
\endpreamble
\postamble
End of customized bst file
\endpostamble
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\askforoverwritefalse
\def\MBopts{\from{merlin.mbs}{ay,ed-au,nmdash,nmd-3,num-xser,isbn,issn,doi,xedn,nfss,}}
% You can change the name of the bst file below:
\generate{\file{tanh.bst}{\MBopts}}
\endbatchfile
```

Save it as .dbj and run tex on it. You will get a `tanh.bst` or
whatever name you write in the `\generate` line.

Then, accoding to [Guido's
answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71227/5872) to
[*Prevent ibid tracking in natbib*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71200/5872), we must edit the
`name.or.dash` macro on the newly created bst file. Here's a patch:

```
--- tanh.bst    2015-12-18 13:11:40.004012993 -0200
+++ tanh_new.bst    2015-12-18 11:19:30.636130895 -0200
@@ -890,7 +890,7 @@
    oldname empty$
      { s 'oldname := s }
      { s oldname =
-         { "---{}---{}---" }
+         { "\andash{" oldname * "}" * }
          { s 'oldname := s }
        if$
      }
```

Apply it with `patch < <patch-filename>`. It only works if your bst file
is named tanh.bst. But it's a single line diff, so you can just edit
the line accordingly (in line 890, replace `{ "---{}---{}---" }` for `{ "\andash{" oldname * "}" * }`).

The MWE from Guido's answer must be enough. Just comment out
`\bibliography` on your first run before running `bibtex`  as
suggested there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{first,
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "First Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2012
}
@Article{second,
  author = "Last, First",
  title = "Second Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
@Article{third,
  author = "More, First",
  title = "Third Title",
  journal = "Journal Name",
  year = 2011
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\andash}[1]{#1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand{\andash}[1]{---{}---{}---}}
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{\renewcommand\andash[1]{#1}}

\begin{document}
Testing normal citations
\cite{first} 
\cite{second}
\cite{third}

\bibliographystyle{tanh.bst}
\nobibliography{\jobname}

Testing \verb|\bibentry|

\bibentry{first}

\bibentry{second}


\bibliography{\jobname}

\section*{More Testing}
Testing \verb|\bibentry| again after the bibliography

\bibentry{second}

\bibentry{first}

\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

---

Or move to [**biblatex**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex). It's worth the effort. For guidance:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
- [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the comprehensive answer. Works great, although commenting out `\bibliography` prior to every run of bibtex makes it a bit of a hassle (especially when using latexmk or something similar). I'll take your advice on moving to biblatex.